# Show that an Ito process is a martingale.

Tags: stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I wonder if someone can help me with this problem:

Let $X_t= \exp\{ -\frac{1}{4c}(1-e^{-2ct}) + \int_{0}^t e^{-cs}dW_s\}$ where $W_s$ is a standard Brownian motion and $c>0$. I'm trying to show that $X_t$ is a martingale.

My attempt goes like this:

> Let $T>t$.
>
> $\mathbb{E}\big[ X_T | \mathcal{F}_t \big] =  \mathbb{E}\big[  \exp\{
> > -\frac{1}{4c}(1-e^{-2cT}) + \int_{0}^T e^{-cs}dW_s\} | \mathcal{F}_t \big]
> > = \\ \mathbb{E}\big[  \exp\{ -\frac{1}{4c}(1-e^{-2cT}) + \int_{0}^t e^{-cs}dW_s +\int_{t}^T e^{-cs}dW_s \} | \mathcal{F}_t \big] $
>
> $\exp\{ \int_{0}^t e^{-cs}dW_s \}$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable so
>   one can take it out of the expectation while $\exp\{ \int_{t}^T
> > e^{-cs}dW_s \}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_t$. So we get:
>
> $  \exp\{ -\frac{1}{4c}(1-e^{-2cT}) + \int_{0}^t e^{-cs}dW_s
> > \}\mathbb{E}\big[ \exp\{\int_{t}^T e^{-cs}dW_s \} \big] $

Is this approach correct? How can I calculate the value of $\mathbb{E}\big[ \exp\{\int_{t}^T e^{-cs}dW_s \} \big]$? I tried using the Ito-formula but had no success.

Comment: I did not check your approach but applying Ito's lemma is more suitable in this case. The expectation you want to compute follows from the fact the integral inside is a Gaussian r.v.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How would you apply Ito's lemma?

Comment: Not sure If I understand your question. You apply it to the exponential process, which is a function of time and another process (the stochastic integral).

Comment: Ok! How do I find the differential of the stochastic integral?

Comment: Or the differential is just $ e^{-ct} dW_t$ by definition?

Comment: Yes. But whatever you can do with differential notation you should also be able to do with integral notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us define:

$f(t):=-\frac{1}{4c}(1-e^{-2ct})$

$Y_{t}:=\int_{0}^{t}e^{-cs}dW_{s}$

so

$dY_{t}=e^{-ct}dW_{t}$

and

$X_{t}=e^{f(t)+Y_{t}}$

From Ito formula, we get:

$dX_{t}=d(e^{f(t)+Y_{t}})=e^{f(t)+Y_{t}}f'(t)dt+e^{f(t)+Y_{t}}dY_{t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{f(t)+Y_{t}}dY_{t}dY_{t}$

$=e^{f(t)+Y_{t}}*(-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2ct})dt+e^{f(t)+Y_{t}}*e^{-ct}dW_{t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{f(t)+Y_{t}}*e^{-2cs}dt$

$=e^{f(t)+Y_{t}}*e^{-ct}dW_{t}=X_{t}e^{-ct}dW_{t}$

Summing up, we have:

$dX_{t}=X_{t}e^{-ct}dW_{t}$,

so

$X_{t}=X_{0}+\int_{0}^{t}X_{s}e^{-cs}dW_{s}$

Now, to solve your problem fully, follow the solution (to be more precise point Ad. 2, for your process $X_{t}$) of this problem: [Link](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/39921/calculating-the-stochastic-integral-of-exp-rts-t/39922#39922)

All the calculations I leave to you.