# Is the Ito process always measurable?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I recently read the literature where there is a sentence that says, "Since the process $X(t), t\in [0,T]$:
$$X(t) = X(0) + \mu(t,X(t)) ~ dt + \sigma(t,X(t)) ~ dW(t)$$
is an Ito process, then $X(t)$ is $\mathcal{F}_T$ measurable." My question is whether this statement is true, and what is the explanation behind it?

Comment: Yes it's true. Heuristically: The way $X$ is defined means it doesn't depend on $X_u,W_u, u>T$. If you want more details, then you'd need to go into the construction of the stochastic integral. See e.g. https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-31089-3 (This is true as well if $T$ is a stopping time and $\mathcal F_T$ is the $\sigma$ field of the $T$ past)

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2881328/show-that-an-ito-process-is-a-martingale

Answer (score 0):

Another result which is commonly quoted is a similar statement -- every Ito integral process $X_t = \int_0^t f(s,B_s) dB_s$ is an $\mathcal{F}_t$-martingale, which implies that $X_t$ must be $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable.

If you want to extend that to any Ito process in a form you defined, i.e.
$$
dX_t = \mu(t, X(t)) dt + \sigma(t, X(t)) dB_t,
$$
you can claim that $X_t$ is a martingale if $\mu \equiv 0$ and
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[ \sqrt{\int \sigma(t)^2 \mathrm{d}t} \right] < \infty.
$$

Indeed, as @Andrew Zhang posted in a comment, the idea of a process being measurable  with respect to a filtration (a time-sequence of $\sigma$-algebras) is that the process does not rely on the information from the "future" -- so $X_t$ is not allowed to depend on what happens after a time $t$.

---

For example, if $B_t$ is standard Brownian motion at time $t$, the processes $B_t, \sin(B_t)$ and $B_{t/2}$ are $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable, while $B_{2t}$ is not.

Another useful example is that Stratonovich integral is not necessarily $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable, since the Stratonovich integral is defined using the middle point of the interval (as opposed to Ito integral which is defined using the left-hand endpoint only), so when you are at a time point, corresponding to the left-hand point, the value for Ito integral is known but Stratonovich is not yet fixed...

Comment: You claim that every ito process, even the ones with positive drift, is a martingale?

Comment: @SBF +1 thanks for pointing this out, changed the text to reflect zero drift. I was originally thinking he calls $X_t = \int_0^t f(...) dB_s$ an Ito process, which obviously is a martingale...

Comment: I think it may be misleading here to claim that all driftless Ito processes are martingales, because we need conditions on $\sigma$ in general and these are not mentioned in here

Comment: @Snoop +1 -- it's not misleading, it is wrong :-) made corrections, please take a look

Comment: @gt6989b now it is improved; in addition, I would say OP and future visitors might appreciate a classic reference (like Karatzas-Shreve, etc any you would prefer)

Comment: @Snoop that I unfortunately have no time for -- please feel free to update the post if you like